# Is the set of measures of all measurable sets with finite measure closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a complete measure space.

Does the set $\{\mu(E)|E\in M ,\mu(E)<\infty\}$ have to be a closed subset of $R$ ?

Thank you

Comment: See if the following argument is correct. Let $A = \{\mu(E)| E\in M, \mu(E)<\infty \}$ Since $\mu$ is continuous at $E$ if $\mu(E)$ is finite. Now, suppose that $\mu(E)<\infty$.
For every $a$ in a neighborhood of $\mu(E)$, there exists a measurable set $F \in M$ st
$a=\mu(F)$ is finite (such that $a=\mu(F) \in A$). Therefore, we can find a sequence $\{a_n \in A\}$, with $a_n \to \mu(E)$. Therefore $A$ is closed. Look liked that I didn't use the fact that $X$ is complete..I may be wrong..

Comment: A closed subset of the set of real numbers. Ii already put the restriction that the measure of these sets is finite

Comment: To be clear, is $\mu$ a _positive_ measure?

Comment: yes This is not a signed measure

Comment: @Randy: apply your proof to the counterexample of anonymous to see what's what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Take the positive integers (or any set containing them) and put a point mass of weight $1-\frac{1}{n}$ at every positive integer. Then $1$ is in the closure of your set but doesn't occur as the measure of any set.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer is given by the fact that [the range of a finite measure is closed](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-04/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6.pdf). Also, the range is convex and hence, by the preceeding result, closed [if the measure space is atomless](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19680006853_1968006853.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. This is a useful partial answer